# How can I fix this bar chart sorting?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2e4y/21/) of the issue I'm currently facing.

Basically, I have an array of objects that I use to draw some bars. After sorting the array, I try to update the bars' `y` positions accordingly but that does not work.

So, this is the scale I use to draw the bars:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(0, numberOfBars))
    .rangeBands([0, numberOfBars * barHeight]);
```

So if I have 3 bars and a bar is 40px high, then I'm mapping 0-3 => 0-120px.

Next, I have a function that uses this scale to return the right `y` position:

```
var y = function(d, i) {
    return yScale(i);
};
```

After drawing the bars using this `y` function, I then sort the data array and try to redraw the bars:

```
barsContainer.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(chartData.users)
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .delay(delay)
      .attr('y', y); // Not working. I thought this would order the bars.
      //.attr('y', 120); // This works though. It moves all the bars to this y.
```

This is where I'm stumped. Since I reordered the array (chartData.users), and since the bars are "joined" with the data, shouldn't the bars change their `y` according to the data's new position in the array?

Comment: [This Sample](http://jsbin.com/ijepod/1/edit) might help

Comment: Thanks! That was most welcome. So instead of sorting the array and then binding it to the data through the `data()` function, all I had to do was call the `sort()` function on the bars. If you want to submit some kind of answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Since you figured it out yourself you deserve the credit. If you found the comment helpful you could just up vote the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was. Since I was sorting an array of objects, D3.js couldn't figure out by itself which array objects matched which DOM objects. So I had to create a key function to identify the objects:

```
var key = function(d) { return d.id }
```

Then, all I had to do was call `data()` using this key function and then `order()`, so the DOM order matches the array order:

```
barsContainer.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(chartData.users, key)
  .order()
  .transition()
    .delay(delay)
    .duration(750)
    .attr('y', y);
```

[Here's the working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2e4y/22/).

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle is very long. I'd recommend paring it back to the bare minimum and seeking help with that specific point.

For example, try testing

```
console.log(chartData.users)
```

immediately after you've declared chartData. It appears to be identical to the sorted one, so it might not be the sorting that's at fault. If you do some more work yourself and then ask a more specific, concise question, you'll probably get more answers.

Good luck with D3!

Comment: I've already reduced a ton of code, you should see the real script lol. It's only the code inside the `setTimeout` function that really matters. And yeah, it's strange that the arrays are identical, but they are not. If you delete the setTimeout function, you'll see that the array starts at `[50, 30, 40]` (exactly like the bars are drawn) and only inside the setTimeout function it is ordered to `[50, 40, 30]`.